# ABRecordCopyValue not working when object doesn't exist

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, option-type, abrecord

This line of code in Swift causes me problems when the address book has a contact with no last name.

I've tried to resolve it a number of ways to no avail. Is there some sort of try catch statement or error handling I can use? Or check if AnyObject is null (the return type of

```
ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty).takeRetainedValue()).
```

I've tried using optional types but it doesn't seem to work since the app stops running the moment you select a contact with no last name - and the line of code below gets highlighted with the error Thread

> 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

```
let lName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as String
```

Answer (score 3):

**ABRecordCopyValue** can actually return nil so you should unwrap it. Also, casting to String didn't work for me so I'm using NSString.

```
if let firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(abContact, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSString {
  println("FIRST NAME: \(firstName)")
}
else {
  println("No Name")
}
```

Another thing you could try is instead of getting the first and lastName individually, you could also try to get the composed name.

```
if let fullName = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(abContact)?.takeRetainedValue() as String? {
  println("Full Name: \(fullName)")
}
```

*P.S: I've also tried all the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001636/swift-checking-unmanaged-address-book-single-value-property-for-nil) but despite of making perfect sense and working when debugging the app, they crashed when I deployed the archive directly into the phone.*