# How to access information about a contact in a Mac OS X address book?

Tags: swift, macos, abaddressbook

When attempting to find a contact in an address book on a Mac, the following compiler error is displayed "Use of unresolved identifier 'kABPersonFirstNameProperty'." I've found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001636/swift-checking-unmanaged-address-book-single-value-property-for-nil) for iOS but can't find a OS X equivalent. According to the docs, `ABRecordCopyValue` is available in the OS X (10.10.5) version I have installed.

```
if let book = ABAddressBook.sharedAddressBook() {
    let nameIsSmith = ABPerson.searchElementForProperty(kABLastNameProperty, label: nil, key: nil, value: "Smith", comparison: ABSearchComparison(kABEqualCaseInsensitive.rawValue))

    let peopleFound = book.recordsMatchingSearchElement(nameIsSmith)

    for person in peopleFound {
        let firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(book, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put `kABPersonFirstNameProperty` in quotes, the error will go away. That's because `ABRecordCopyValue` expects `property` to be a `CFString`. However, this doesn't solve all of the problems because it looks like `book` needs to be an `ABAddressBookRef` but is instead `ABAddressBook`. I thought `ABAddressBook.sharedAddressBook()` should return the ref but apparently not. Hope this helps and sorry I couldn't be more helpful!

Comment: @Jake thanks for your help. I ended up using `if let firstName = person.valueForProperty(kABFirstNameProperty) as? String {...}` instead of `ABRecordCopyValue`.